# Display name over clicked/hovered node? (D3.js version 4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Currently I have names of my nodes display. I think I would like to only  have the name of a node display if the user clicks on the node or hovers over it (will decide after testing what I like).

To display text I have this currently:

```
var nodes_text = svg.selectAll(".nodetext")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "nodetext slds-text-heading--label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("dx", -20)
        .attr("dy", 20)
        .text(function(d) {
            return  d.name;
        });
```

My initial thought was to delete the last statement in the above code and move it to a "onclick" event...

```
svg.select("circle").on("click", function(d) {
svg.select(".nodetext").text(function(d) {
            return  d.name;
        });

});
```

However this only works if I click my central node for some reason. Was wondering if there is a more obvious way. My node data is stored in an array called "nodes."

EDIT: Here is JFiddle of some test data that shows basic problem. Clicking purple node works but others do not
https://jsfiddle.net/mg8b46aj/1/

Comment: You are always selecting the first element. If you want help, you're gonna have to provide the code for the circles and a sample of the data array. Preferably, if you want help faster, create a jsfiddle/plunker/codepen/blocks/whatever. Meanwhile, I'm voting to close this: *"Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Comment: I can provide jfiddle I suppose if it lets me edit question. Says shortest code necessary so didn't want to provide whole program I suppose. I will try to simplify it though.

Comment: Good, I just retracted my vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in code

1. You are binding same data for `node-circles` and `node-text` elements, so it makes sense if you group them inside one `g` element
2. You are trying to handle click event on only one element
   `svg.select("circle").on("click",handler)`

   this selects  and handles events only last one element , you have to use `selectAll` - `svg.selectAll("circle").on("click",handler)`
3. Same thing inside handler function
   `svg.select(".nodetext").text(function(d) { return  d.name; });`
   you are also selecting last element here
4. Instead of setting `text` attribute on click, it's better if you set them before and just `display & hide` it on `hover & click`

   As Gerardo mentioned, you have to filter nodes based on circle click,
   but what if two nodes have same name?  I have also generated `id` for nodes and have filtered them using that id

See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mg8b46aj/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two different selections for the texts and the circles (not a group with those elements, which is the traditional approach), a possible solution is filtering the texts based on the clicked circle:

```
svg.selectAll("circle").on("click", function(d) {
    svg.selectAll(".nodetext").filter(function (e){ 
        return e.name === d.name})
    .text(function(d) {
        return  d.name;
    });
```

Here is the update fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2L9rzqbs/